# Send entire list or just a page to the client?

Tags: asp.net, performance, client-server

I've been retrieving data from the **database** and **paging** it based on a **filter** primarily sent by the client via `HttpPost`. To make myself as clear as possible, I'll give an example:

1. The user (client side) opens a **customer search** page;
2. Server receives the initial request and **queries** a list of **all** customers, filtering the **first 20** and only returning a list with these 20 rows, a **page index** and the **total rows count** back to the client;
3. The client receives the 20 rows, the page index and rows count. The `HTML` is rendering in such a way that there will be a table with a footer which contains paging, accordingly to the rows count;
4. Once the user clicks on a link to another page on the footer, the server receives the new request and do the same query as before, but now **skips** the first 20 results.

The performance was satisfying so far, when the only bottleneck was that waiting could be quite a bit from page browsing.

But now it became a problem because I want to implement a search that updates upon insertion. User types a character and the result is filtered to match whatever is contained in that Textbox.

What can I do about that? Should I send the **entire collection** to the client?

Am I achieving the best theoretical performance by paging **before** transferring data to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pull only the pages (record limit) requested by the customer from db and whenever he requests new page pull them again from DB.

Either to store the result in session or in-memory is purely depends on how your application runs. Considering given use case, apply the pagination in db itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with asp.net Gridview Control paging opition